# Javascript - How can I replace text in HTML with text in script

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I was thinking getelementbyid but i don't know how to make it work

Like the title, here is what I mean

For example I have in HTML:

```
<p>fw_93</p>
<p>fw_94</p>
<p>fw_93</p>
```

So what I want is to make script to replace those fw_93 fw_94 to what I want.

For example
Instead of displaying "fw_93" I want it to display "9.3". Same with fw_94 to 9.4

Comment: What are you trying?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and Code. There are other questions that are duplicates of this one

Comment: on which action/event you wants to replace?

Comment: So you don't understand the question?

Comment: what mean of :replace those fw_93 fw_94 to what , you have to pass something in some condition, those conditions are not here

Comment: We do not provide code on demand. Ask a proper question. We do not know what will trigger the change, what are the rules to find the paragraphs? content? Search for content or change all first Ps?

Comment: It should work like ID, each ID have different text to display, like if there is ID "fw_93" then display 9.3

Comment: You do not have any ID. An ID would be `<p id="fw_93">FW 93</p>`

Comment: I am new to javascript. I know I have to use getelementbyid but I dont know how to make it work

Answer (score 1):

Replace fw_ with nothing, divide the number by 10:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p'), function(el) {
  el.innerHTML = parseInt(el.innerHTML.replace(/[A-Za-z_]*/, '')) / 10;
});
```

```html
<p>fw_93</p>
<p>fw_94</p>
<p>fw_93</p>
```

Comment: I like the 'divide by 10' logic. It also assumes only ever be 2 digits, but can only go off OP details provided

Answer (score 1):

1. Okay so select the tags.
2. Loop over the collection
3. read the html
4. match the string
5. replace the html

```js
var ps = document.querySelectorAll("p");
for (var i=0; i<ps.length; i++) {
    var p = ps[i]; 
    var txt = p.innerHTML; //.textContent
    var updated = txt.replace(/.+(\d)(\d)/, "$1.$2");
    p.innerHTML = updated;
}
```

```html
<p>fw_93</p>
<p>fw_94</p>
<p>fw_93</p>
```

Comment: Nice solution, though it assumes only ever 2 digits. But OP hasn't been specific about valid inputs, I just assume as OP mentions ID then it might range more than 2 digits... anyway, I'm just thinking out loud

Comment: just matching the test cases provided, not that hard to change the reg exp to match other cases.

Comment: haha, it's not that hard to solve the problem in the first place either, yet here the question is!

Comment: Not just replace to digit. I do want to replace to text

Comment: @superquanganh um, that is what it does... Did you hit the "*Run code Snipplet*" button and see what the output is?

Answer (score 0):

**Using JQuery**

Not sure why I did it with JQuery, guess I wasn't paying enough attention. No point in me re-writing as there are already good answers in JS. Though I will leave this in case it's of use to anyone that *is* using JQuery.

---

You can loop though each `<p>` element and covert the contents, something like this:

```js
    $("p").each(function() {
      var text = $(this).html();
      var text = text.substring(text.indexOf("_") + 1);
      var text = text[0] + "." + text.substring(1);
      $(this).html(text);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>fw_93</p>
<p>fw_94</p>
<p>fw_93</p>
```

You may need to add validation depending on how reliable your input is.

Note that the code makes the following assumptions:

1. There will always be a `_` followed by at least 2 digits
2. The `.` will always go after the first digit

Comment: `text.substring(text.indexOf("_") + 1);` == `text.split("_")[1]`

Answer (score -2):

Your HTML:

```
  <p id="p1">init_value</p>
```

Your JS:

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "new_value";
```

Comment: how we got new value? it's static better to direct assign new value in <p>